# Obtaining AuthProvider for current user on firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am trying to detect the AuthProvider for a logged-in user in order to provide an easy way to reauthenticate using "reauthenticateWithPopup".

The easiest way would be directly getting the corresponding AuthProvider object from the currentUser, however, I think it's not possible (please correct me if I'm wrong).

The other option would be getting the firebase.auth.currenUser.providerId and doing a switch/case clause to create a firebase.auth.AuthProvider. I personally don't like this option much since I would have to do a switch/case over strings (e.g. "google.com"). However, this was the best solution I could think of.

Unfortunately as I was implementing it, I realized that firebase.auth.currenUser.providerId would always return "firebase", even if I would be logged-in from google or using email/password. Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

I can see that if I access currentUser.providerData, there is an array with all the available providers for this user. However, this is a list and I'm not sure if I would be selecting the currently used one in case there would be more than one for this user.

Additional information: using angularfire2 v4

Comment: Each provider in the currentUser.providerData has a providerId: firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].providerId. You can use that to reauthenticate the user. You can also provide all the options to reauthenticate for the current user and let the user decide which one to use.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought of doing. However, I was wondering if there was a direct way of knowing the one that was used to authenticate this time. If the user has multiple ways of authenticating (e.g. the account is linked in with google, facebook etc.), then there should be a way of obtaining the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to iterate through the providerData list. You could also parse the Firebase ID token using some JWT parser and check the firebase.sign_in_provider field. This will contain the method of authentication used to obtain the ID token:

```
{
 "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/PROJECT_ID",
 "aud": "PROJECT_ID",
 "auth_time": 1495126200,
 "user_id": "1234567890",
 "sub": "1234567890",
 "iat": 1495126200,
 "exp": 1495129800,
 "email": "user@example.com",
 "email_verified": true,
 "firebase": {
   "identities": {
     "google.com": [
       "0987654321"
     ],
     "email": [
       "user@example.com"
     ]
   },
   "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
 }
}
```

Comment: I see, I guess there is no built in function inside angularfire2 to do that? It looks like a nice feature to have.

Answer (score 0):

This is for a webapp?

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Straight from the docs, check for this in your script, if the users signed in execute code, if not redirect to register/login

Answer (score 0):

To get current user loggedin, try this

```
 import {
      AngularFire,
      AngularFireAuth
    } from 'angularfire2';

    constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
      this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
        console.log(auth)
      }); 
    }
```